# Bandwidth of CW modulation (morse code)?

Tags: communication

How can I relate the bandwidth required by a morse code signal over RF to:

- the length of a dash, and the length of a dot
- the time between dots and dashes
- the speed of keying?

Are all applicable to the bandwidth of the channel?  Can I model this as a function?

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/122177/8627

Comment: The OP has added that the carrier is RF, which wasn't clear before... I thought it could just be a wire.

Comment: Duplicate?  Where?  The related thread linked is my own thread, and it is a different question.  What I'm asking here wasn't answered there.

Answer (score 1):

On off keying of a carrier with a rectangular pulse would occupy a bandwidth (to the first sidelobe in the sinc function spectrum) of 2/T where T is the pulse width. From this you can determine the bandwidth occupied by a dot, a dash (3x dot duration) and the space between symbols (which is the same as a dot).

Comment: Why is there bandwidth occupied by the space between symbols?

Comment: Also, is the maximum bandwidth when a rectangular pulse is used, or will non-rectangular waveforms (as generated by humans and real radios) occupy more?

Comment: Typically, real radios use RC time constants or similar to drive pulse shaping and so occupy substantially less bandwidth than "hard" keying would, but there is a tradeoff in intelligibility.